# Qt 5.4 OS X how to use a QAction in both a QMenu and a QToolBar, but show the icon only in the QToolbar

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, qmenu, qaction

Using Qt 5.4 on OS X (Yosemite), I have a `QAction` that has an icon.  I want the icon to show in the `QToolbar` that I add the action to.  This works fine.  However, I do NOT want the icon to show in the QMenu that I add the action to.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Qt::AA_DontShowIconsInMenus` attribute in your application or individually by QAction::setIconVisibleInMenu(bool visible). Straight from [Qt's docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#iconVisibleInMenu-prop%20qt's%20docs):

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontShowIconsInMenus);  // Icons are *no longer shown* in menus
// ...
QAction *myAction = new QAction();
// ...
myAction->setIcon(SomeIcon);
myAction->setIconVisibleInMenu(true);   // Icon *will* be shown in menus for *this* action.
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that did it!  For reference:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#iconVisibleInMenu-prop and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum